# What are acoustic modes?

Tags: wave-equation

In the context below

> "In Pidduck [8, 9] it was suggested that the water compressibility be taken into account to resolve the instantaneity paradox in the well-known Cauchy-Poisson problem. Pidduck described the water flow as isothermal and weakly compressible just as it appears in CMA-SPH. A linear analysis was performed verifying that the weakly compressible model captures the depth decaying incompressible solution to leading order with accuracy of order $O(1/c^2)$. However, it was shown that given appropriate initial and boundary conditions, the weak compressibility assumption also permits an infinite set of essentially non-attenuating high-frequency depth oscillatory **acoustic modes** that depend on c and the water depth".

Any sort of help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Sounds more like fluid dynamics?

Comment: @copper.hat
Or fourier analysis?